# Maintaining foreign key relations when casting to dict

Tags: python, ponyorm

Say I have the following db classes:

```
class Person(DB.Entity):
  id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
  name = Required(str, 100)
  cars = Set('Car')
```

```
class Car(DB.Entity):
  id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
  owner = Required(Person, cascade_delete=False)
```

When I perform a select on Person, I get the associated cars:

```
people = Person.select(lambda p: p.name == 'Jaewon')
```

However, I would like to return `people` as a Dict instead of a Pony object, so it can be used in the calling methods. If I do the following, I get `people` as a dictionary, but lose the `car` key:

```
return people[:]
```

What is the proper way to pull values from the database and return them as dict without dropping their associated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Entity.to_dict`](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#Entity.to_dict) function has a `related_objects` keyword argument.

You can use it to include the objects in the dicts.

If you want the to-many relationships too, you also need the `with_collections` argument.

```py
people = Person.select(lambda p: p.name == 'Jaewon')

people = [
  person.to_dict(
    related_objects=True,
    with_collections=True
  )
  for person in people
]
```

This doesn't automatically recurse, and you will have to walk the tree yourself to create the full dict.

```py
for person in people:
  person['cars'] = [car.to_dict(**kwargs) for car in person['cars']]
```

Comment: This worked for the first level, thanks! Unfortunately, the `cars` object is still a list of Entities, and not a list of dicts. Do you know if there are any other options to convert to dict the whole way down, or should I just iterate over the values of `person` and cast them to dicts manually?

Comment: @rgahan You need to iterate over the objects and convert them to dicts all the way down. I've edited the answer to add the link for the documentation.